# Objects not arranged how I expected them to

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm working on a p5.js project for class, and I ran into an issue while coding.

Right now, the code is supposed to generate 5 objects under the class Building, and then use that to draw 5 equally spaced boxes in a straight line, but for some reason, the boxes are not equally spaced, and I have no idea why.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```js
//basically, I want this code to generate 5 equally spaced rectangular prisms centered on the screen

let buildings = []

class Building {
  constructor(spot, h, w) { //spot is basically how far along the line of buildings a given building should be (0 is at the beginning, 4 is at the end because it counts from 0), h and w are height and width, adn are currently the same for all objects for simplicity
    this.spot = spot;
    this.h = h;
    this.w = w;
  }

  create() {
    box(this.w, this.h, this.w)
    translate((this.spot*160)-200, 0, 0) //this is the line that is giving me issues. it SHOULD be moving the boxes so that they are equally spaced from each other, but instead they give me this weird almost exponential spacing. additionally, if the y or z are changed, a similar thing occurs, with the boxes just not being where youd expect them to be
  }
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 600, WEBGL);
  for (let i=0; i<5; i++) { //add 5 building objects to the array
    buildings[i] = new Building(i, 400, 40)
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  for (let Building of buildings) { //draw the 5 buildings
    Building.create()
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.5.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`translate()` accumulates. Use `push()` before `translate()` to save the transformation matrix, then `pop()` afterwards to restore it.

Also, `translate()` first, then draw your boxes.

```js
class Building {
  constructor(spot, h, w) {
    this.spot = spot;
    this.h = h;
    this.w = w;
  }

  draw() {
    push();
    translate(this.spot * 160 - 200, 0, 0);
    box(this.w, this.h, this.w);
    pop();
  }
}

const buildings = [...Array(5)].map((_, i) =>
  new Building(i, 400, 40)
);

function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 600, WEBGL);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  for (const building of buildings) {
    building.draw();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

`spot` may not be the clearest variable name.

Answer (score 1):

[Docs](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/translate)

> Transformations are cumulative and apply to everything that happens after and subsequent calls to the function accumulates the effect. For example, calling translate(50, 0) and then translate(20, 0) is the same as translate(70, 0). If translate() is called within draw(), the transformation is reset when the loop begins again.

Example:

```
translate(30, 20);
rect(0, 0, 55, 55);
```

As you can see, first translate then draw

But it's still isn't enough in your code, because you will move things further and further so just reset it after translation:

```
create() {
  const offset = (this.spot*160)-200
  translate(offset, 0, 0)
  box(this.w, this.h, this.w)
  translate(-offset, 0, 0)
}
```

```js
//basically, I want this code to generate 5 equally spaced rectangular prisms centered on the screen

let buildings = []

class Building {
  constructor(spot, h, w) { //spot is basically how far along the line of buildings a given building should be (0 is at the beginning, 4 is at the end because it counts from 0), h and w are height and width, adn are currently the same for all objects for simplicity
    this.spot = spot;
    this.h = h;
    this.w = w;
  }

  create() {
    push()
    translate((this.spot * 160) - 200, 0, 0)
    box(this.w, this.h, this.w)
    pop()
  }
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 600, WEBGL);
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) { //add 5 building objects to the array
    buildings[i] = new Building(i, 400, 40)
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  for (let Building of buildings) { //draw the 5 buildings
    Building.create()
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.5.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Or even better:

```
create() {
  push()
  translate((this.spot*160)-200, 0, 0)
  box(this.w, this.h, this.w)
  pop()
}
```

```js
//basically, I want this code to generate 5 equally spaced rectangular prisms centered on the screen

let buildings = []

class Building {
  constructor(spot, h, w) { //spot is basically how far along the line of buildings a given building should be (0 is at the beginning, 4 is at the end because it counts from 0), h and w are height and width, adn are currently the same for all objects for simplicity
    this.spot = spot;
    this.h = h;
    this.w = w;
  }

  create() {
    const offset = (this.spot*160)-200
    translate(offset, 0, 0)
    box(this.w, this.h, this.w)
    translate(-offset, 0, 0)
  }
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 600, WEBGL);
  for (let i=0; i<5; i++) { //add 5 building objects to the array
    buildings[i] = new Building(i, 400, 40)
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  for (let Building of buildings) { //draw the 5 buildings
    Building.create()
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.5.0/p5.js"></script>
```